# MSBuild publish web project from command line does Package instead of FileSystem

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, publish-profiles

I have a web project that I am publishing from the command line, using a publish profile that does a few additional tasks (excludes some files and folders, grunt, publishing another project in turn).

One two machines (A and B), it works fine from right-click > Publish... in Visual Studio, and choosing the correct publish profile.

Historically, on both machines, it has also worked with the following command line:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myProfile  /v:n
```

However now, machine B is not publishing correctly.

The publish profile is configured with `<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod` at the top, however from the logs, it is attempting a `Package` publish type instead, for no apparent reason.

Here is the full publish profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <publishUrl>..\Production</publishUrl>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
        <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Content;Scripts;Pages</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
        <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>index-dev.html;index.html;debug.html;JSLintNet.json;Gruntfile.js;package.json;packages.config;publishall.bat;publishapi.bat</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
        <BuildDependsOn>
            $(BuildDependsOn);
            RunGrunt;
            PublishApi;
        </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="RunGrunt">
        <Message Text="Running grunt production..." />
        <Exec Command="grunt production" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="PublishApi">
        <Message Text="Publishing API..." />
        <Exec Command="publishapi" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

As you'd expect, because it is just doing a `Package`, no files ever appear in the `publishUrl` directory. Again, the publish profile works fine from VS2013, using right-click publish.

In the log on machine A I get this excerpt:

```
**ValidatePublishProfileSettings**:
  Validating PublishProfile(myProfile) settings.
```

But in machine B it doesn't appear.

Later in the log on machine A it contains:

```
**WebFileSystemPublish**:
  Creating directory "..\Production".
  Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\cache.manifest to C:\SVN\Trunk\src\Web Sites\MyProject\..\Production\cache.manifest.
  Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Global.asax to C:\SVN\Trunk\src\Web Sites\MyProject\..\Production\Global.asax.
  Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config to C:\SVN\Trunk\src\Web Sites\MyProject\..\Production\Web.config.
  Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MyProject.dll to C:\SVN\Trunk\src\Web Sites\MyProject\..\Production\Blithe.Web.Collect.dll.
```

but later in the log on machine B, in place of the above, it contains:

```
**Package**:   
  Invoking Web Deploy to generate the package with the following settings:   
  $(LocalIisVersion) is 7  
  $(DestinationIisVersion) is 7   
  $(UseIis) is True   
  $(IisUrl) is <<<some url>>>  
  $(IncludeIisSettings) is False  
  $(_DeploymentUseIis) is False   
  $(DestinationUseIis) is False
```

The only difference I can think of between the two machines, is that I installed an update on machine B (the problem machine) for 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS2013) - 2.3'. Any ideas how and why this might have broken it?

I tried adding `/p:PublishProfileRootFolder="Properties\PublishProfiles"` as mentioned [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/21396873/1061602) but this didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding:

`/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`

to the command worked.

Machine B had Visual Studio 2008 installed on it as well, whereas Machine A didn't. Setting the version to 12.0, or even 11.0 works. Setting it to 10.0 ignores the publish profile and just does a package install.

Surprisingly it seems to default to 10.0.

This issue did not emerge until the update to [Azure SDK 2.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/announcing-release-of-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-and-azure-sdk-2-3.aspx), which DID have some changes to Web Publish, so that may well have led to this issue.